# Bypass DND and Silent Mode in Android Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, do-not-disturb

I need to bypass the DND (Do Not Disturb) and Silent mode for specific push notifications (Only for certain channels).

There are many old questions related to this topic. But I didn't see any latest discussions.

Could any expertise guide here with JAVA-based implementation?

Comment: If you find a way to do that, please report the bug to google.